# Skip lines starting with a character and delete lines matching second column lesser than a value

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have file with following format :

```
Qil
Lop
A D E
a 1 10
b 2 21
c 3 22
d 4 5
3 5 9
```

I need to skip lines that start with pattern 'Qil' or 'Lop' or 'A D E' and ones where the third column has a value greater than 10 and save the entire thing in 2 different files with formats as shown below.
Example output files :

```
Output file 1
    Qil
    Lop
    A D E
    a 1 10
    d 4 5
    3 5 9 

Output file 2
a
d
3
```

My code :

```
while read -r line; if [[ $line == "A" ]] ||[[ $line == "Q" ]]||[[ $line == "L" ]] ; then 
awk '$2 < "11" { print $0 }' test.txt
awk '$2 < "11" { print $1 }' test1.txt
done < input.file
```

Comment: what about `A D` ??why its in the output ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^Qil$|^Lop$|^A D E$/{
   val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
   next
}
$3<=10{
   if(!flag){
       print val > "file1"
       flag=1
   }
   print > "file1"
   if(!a[$1]++){
       print $1> "file2"
   }
}'  Input_file
```

This will create 2 output files named `file1` and `file2` as per OP's requirements.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single `awk`:

```
awk '$1 !~ /^[QLA]/ && $2 <= 10' file
```

```
1 10
4 5
5 9
```

---

If you want to print only first column then use:

```
awk '$1 !~ /^[QLA]/ && $2 <= 10 { print $1 }' file
```

```
1
4
5
```

Comment: Hi I need to have Q L A D in first file as shown in the question above..

Comment: Your code is not helping me when I have more than one letter in lines which I want to skip..

Comment: Ok just remove $ feom regex or check updated answer